# Where do you install applications in Ubuntu which will be accessible by all users?

Tags: ubuntu, installation

In Windows, software is just installed centrally in /programs but in Ubuntu its usually stored in the users local directory. When I install programs via add/remove they appear for my other user accounts as well which is great.

But I have downloaded an application that's been wrapped in a tar file. It doesn't need to be compiled, just needs a home and a launcher. When I installed it in my user account it worked fine but its only visible to me. Where should I install it so it's useable by all users?

The software in question is not available in the repositories.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> but in Ubuntu its usually stored in the users local directory.

Hmm. This isn't really true (or I misunderstood what you meant). *Usually* programs are installed using [Ubuntu's package management system](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoftwareManagement) (deb packages), and they are available system-wide for all users. This is by far the preferred method of installing software.

When (on rare occasions) installing something *outside the package management system*, I tend to use `/usr/local/programs`, and create specific subfolders there for different programs. Often, I'll also put a symlink (or simple startup script) under `/usr/local/bin` to make it easier to launch these applications. Of course, `/opt` or any other location would do just as well, as long as you make sure all users can access the files and directories ([as Bobby pointed out](https://superuser.com/questions/108725/where-do-you-install-applications-in-ubuntu-which-will-be-accessible-by-all-users/108726#108726)).

If you want such programs to appear in the start menu of your desktop environment, you'll need to take care of it yourself. E.g. [this](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/howto-add-entries-in-gnome-menu.html) shows how to add entries (for one user?), assuming you use Gnome. I'm sure there's a way to add it for *all users*, but off the top of my head I'm not sure how; maybe others can help you there.

Answer (score 2):

What application? Please check if it isn't available through an external repository. Otherwise, copy it into the /opt folder and use `chmod` and `chown` to allow everyone to use it.