# Install Git on a Media Temple (dv) 4.0 server

Tags: installation, git, vps

I'm trying to install Git on my [Media Temple (dv) 4.0 server](http://mediatemple.net/webhosting/dv/).

I've followed [these instructions](http://wiki.mediatemple.net/w/%28dv%29_4.0:Install_GIT). It seems to have "installed", as there are a boat-load of files in the `/root/git-2012-06-06` directory.

However, when I perform any git command in the server, I receive this message:

```
git: command not found
```

My assumption is that something, somewhere is not configured properly, but I have no idea where to start. Could anybody lend a hand / offer some pointers?

I did perform the `make install`.

The output of `which git` is `/usr/bin/which: no git in (/usr/kerberos/sbin:/usr/kerberos/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/root/bin)`

The output of `echo $PATH` is `/usr/kerberos/sbin:/usr/kerberos/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/root/bin`

`/usr/local/bin` contains:

```
ftpcount
ftptop
git
gitk
git-shell
git-upload-pack
ftpdctl
ftpwho
git-cvsserver
git-receive-pack
git-upload-archive
prxs
```

Comment: Did you forget to `make install` at the end? What's the output of `which git`, and the output of `echo $PATH`? What's the output of the commands you executed? Is there a `git` in `/usr/local/bin`? Why are you administering an internet-connected server when you don't know what you're doing?

Comment: Thanks for your response @DanielBeck. I've added responses to your questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `/usr/local/bin` to your path, e.g. by adding the following to `~/.bashrc` (assuming `bash` is your shell):

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

More information [here](https://superuser.com/questions/284342/what-are-path-and-other-environment-variables-and-how-can-i-set-or-use-them). You were essentially hit by the problem I mention [here](https://superuser.com/questions/371653/linux-which-is-most-appropriate-directory-to-place-an-exectuable-for-all-user/371655#371655), `/usr/local/[s]bin` sometimes not being on the `PATH`.

Alternatively, learn to type the full path to `git`: `/usr/local/bin/git`.

Comment: Terrific. That's worked a dream. Thanks for your help.